# SQL Server Profiler

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-profiler

I have been told that SQL Profiler makes changes to the MSDB when it is run. Is this true and if so what changes does it make?

MORE INFO

The reason I ask is that we have a DBA who wants us to range a change request when we run the profiler on a live server. Her argument is that it makes changes to the DB's which should be change controlled.

Comment: It probably just registers itself as a running trace, in the syscollections* tables, etc.

Comment: why are you concerned about what SQL Profiler does internally? It is a tried and tested tool, and if it had unwanted side-effects I'm sure someone would have screamed loudly until it was fixed...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Starting a trace adds a row into [`msdb.sys.traces`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178579.aspx), stopping the trace removes the row. However `msdb.sys.traces` is a view over an internal table valued function and is not backed by any physical storage. To prove this, set `msdb` to `read_only`, start a trace, observer the new row in `msdb.sys.traces`, stop the trace, remember to turn `msdb` back `read_write`. Since a trace can be started in the Profiler *event when `msdb` is read only* it is clear that normally there is no write into msdb that can occur.

Now before you go and grin to your dba, she is actually right. Profiler traces can pose a significant stress on a live system because the traced events must block until they can generate the trace record. Live, busy, systems may experience blocking on resources of type `SQLTRACE_BUFFER_FLUSH`, `SQLTRACE_LOCK`, `TRACEWRITE` and other. Live traces (profiler) are usualy worse, file traces (sp_trace_create) are better, but still can cause issues. So starting new traces should definetly something that the DBa should be informed about and very carefully considered.

Answer (score 1):

The only ones I know happen when you schedule a trace to gather periodic information - a job is added.

Comment: You mean a SQL Agent job? A trace does not require a SQL Agent job to run.

Comment: @Philip Kelly: I did not say that a job is automatically created. I said that when you schedule a trace, a job will be created.

Comment: Do you mean a specific SQL Agent job, or a background job/task?

Comment: As a part of regular work, my DBA scheduled profiler runs. He created a SQL Server job for that.

Comment: Got it -- your DBA created a job that creates the trace. (I've done that too.) These comments make that clear, so I'll reverse my downvote.

Answer (score 0):

That's not the case as far as I'm aware (other than the trivial change noted by others).

What changes are you referring to?

Answer (score 0):

Nothing I have ever read, heard, or seen says that SQL Profiler or anything it does or uses has any impact on the MSDB database. (SQL Profiler is, essentially, a GUI wrapped around the trace routines.) It is of course possible to configure a specific setup/implementation to do, well, anything, and perhaps that's what someone is thinking of.

This sounds like a kind of "urban legend". I recommend that you challenge it -- get the people who claim it to be true to provide proof.